# cmake error with grpc in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, cmake, grpc

When trying to build tensorflow using cmake, I got the following error. I'm not sure whether it's an issue related to tensorflow or grpc. Any idea on what's going on?

This is on Mac OS Sierra.

steps to reproduce:

```
# clone tensorflow repo
# in tensorflow directory
cd tensorflow/contrib/cmake
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python3
make tf_tutorials_example_trainer
```

Errors:

```
# ...
Scanning dependencies of target tf_tutorials_example_trainer
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tf_tutorials_example_trainer.dir/Users/kevenwang/VirtualBoxShared/another_tf/tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable tf_tutorials_example_trainer
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ares_cancel", referenced from:
      on_readable_cb(grpc_exec_ctx*, void*, grpc_error*) in libgrpc_unsecure.a(grpc_ares_ev_driver_posix.cc.o)
      on_writable_cb(grpc_exec_ctx*, void*, grpc_error*) in libgrpc_unsecure.a(grpc_ares_ev_driver_posix.cc.o)
  "_ares_destroy", referenced from:
      grpc_ares_ev_driver_unref(grpc_ares_ev_driver*) in libgrpc_unsecure.a(grpc_ares_ev_driver_posix.cc.o)

  ...

      _grpc_ares_ev_driver_create in libgrpc_unsecure.a(grpc_ares_ev_driver_posix.cc.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [tf_tutorials_example_trainer] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tf_tutorials_example_trainer.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/tf_tutorials_example_trainer.dir/rule] Error 2
```

Comment: gRPC indeed uses c-ares as a third party dependency, so this might indeed be a gRPC problem, but it's hard to tell without more info. Consider filing a gRPC issue on github and please provide more details - what gRPC version, does it work on other platforms, etc.

Comment: Also, you can try compiling with c-ares disabled (define GRPC_ARES=0) or with c-ares pre-installed on your system (gRPC_CARES_PROVIDER=package cmake argument)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you install the grpc lib by Homebrew.

In that case , you need to link the c-ares lib.

e.g.

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(demo "/usr/local/lib/libcares.a" ...)